# Is my new conditional logic correct for Game of Life rules? (differentiating BIRTH and LIVING conditions)

Tags: java, arrays, conditional-statements, conways-game-of-life

I previously asked for help looking over my Game of Life code here:[Issue with Game of life code method? (User interface is complete but actual GOL methods aren't generating what they should)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35952931/issue-with-game-of-life-code-method-user-interface-is-complete-but-actual-gol) and received feedback (except to my last question which formed the basis to this question), but I wasn't sure how to post an updated question with my code formatted correctly in reply.

Here is my updated code to the rules only for Game of Life. I tried to factor in the suggestion that I needed to make the BIRTH and LIVING condition differentiate. But it still doesn't work and does even less than it did before (now it blanks after the first generation instead of generating nonsense). If someone could look it over and tell me if my logic is true that would be very helpful as it seems like it should work given the format of:

```
if ((map = true) && ((count == 2) || (count == 3))){
map2 = true;} else {map2 = false;}

if (map = false) && count == 3)
map2 = true; 
.
.
.
update map = map2;
```

Code:

```
for (int j = 0; j < y; j++) {
      for (int i = 0; i < x; i++) {
        if ((map[j][i] = true) && ((neighborCount[j][i] == 2) || (neighborCount[j][i] == 3))){//alive/dead
          map2[j][i] = true;
        } else {map2[j][i] = false;
        }

        if ((map[j][i] = false) && (neighborCount[j][i] == 3)){//birth
          map2[j][i] = true;
        }
        }
    } 

    map = map2;
  }
```

Comment: You'll likely get more useful information by running your code with a debugger than you will here. This way you can test the code and see exactly where it's not functioning as you expect that it should. In the very least it should help you isolate your error, which if you're still stuck, would allow you to ask a better question and create and post a valid [mcve].

Comment: Another tip: strive to make your classes smallish individually testable units of code. This will make debugging **much** easier. Always remember the "single responsibility rule" where each class has one and only one responsibility.

Comment: Hint: replace `map[i][j] =  true` with `map[i][j] == true`, or better yet with only `map[i][j]`.  Did your compiler issue a warning of the kind "Possibly incorrect assignment..."?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at this condition:

```
if ((map[j][i] = true) && ... ) {
```

Notice that you're writing

```
(map[j][i] = true)
```

which means "set `map[j][i]` to be true, then evaluate to `true`." In other words, this changes the contents of `map[j][i]` (oops!) and then continues on to the rest of the if statement.

I believe you meant to write something like

```
if ((map[j][i] == true) && ... ) {
```

or, even better,

```
if (map[j][i] && ... ) {
```

which means the same thing and doesn't risk the accidental assignment.

Similarly, here you write

```
if ((map[j][i] = false) && ...
```

which updates `map[j][i]` to be false (oops!). I think you meant

```
if ((map[j][i] == false) && ...
```

or, better yet,

```
if (!map[j][i] && ...
```

As a note, many compilers will issue warnings if they see code like what you wrote, since it's almost always the wrong thing to do. You may want to check to see whether you had such a warning. If so, now you know what that means! If not, you might want to crank up the warning level on your compiler so that it's less likely that you can make mistakes like this in the future.

Comment: Thank you for that catch! That definitely fixes this part of the code. The overall code still doesn't work, but at least now I can be fairly certain whatever the ongoing issue is it likely isn't in the rules.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe with more parenthesis :

```
if ((map[j][i] = true) && ((neighborCount[j][i] == 2) || (neighborCount[j][i] == 3)))
```

Comment: `(false && true || true) -> true` != `(false && (true || true)) -> false`. Or I am wrong ?

Comment: You're right. Updated. Unfortunately that still doesn't fix the problem.

Comment: It doesn't seem incorrect. neighborCount[j][i] gets countNeighbors (int i,int j, map), a method which takes two ints and a boolean array "map" and references and counts the 8 elements surrounding a middle element in a 3x3 array).

Comment: I did upvote Opsse's answer. I don't have a reputation of 15 points so it just said "thanks for the feedback" and reverted.

Comment: I think that you missed the major error in the code. See my answer for details.

Comment: Yep, it's such big, that no one noticed